# Redirection of page in controller

Tags: html, jsp, redirect, controller

I am writing the code in controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lead/*.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView lead(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String role=null;
    String baseURL = "lead/";
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
```

From this it will check role from database(I have written the logic for that and it is working) But if I write the condition in controller only after above code

```
if(role!="LEAD"){
system.out.println("You don't have access!!");
return new ModelAndView("redirect:error.html");}
```

But it is giving me error as The page isn’t redirecting properly.That means I don't want to give access to those who does not have role as "LEAD" .Hence I am redirecting the page But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`if(role!="LEAD"){` should be `if(!"LEAD".equals(role)){` at least.